# "I will see you on Monday morning" vs. "I will see you Monday morning"

Tags: prepositions, time

> 1. I will see you **on** Monday morning.
> 2. I will see you Monday morning.

Is the second version idiomatic and grammatically correct? Which version do native speakers prefer to use more?

Comment: Option 2 sounds like American English to me as I would prefer the first but neither is wrong.

Comment: There is nothing AmE or BrE. Both are fine in both.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition on with days of the week and the verb saw:

- see someone on Monday
- see someone Monday

Both are correct; both are used. There is no semantic difference.

Other verbs also can take on or not with days of the week:

- go on Monday
- go Monday
- leave Monday
- leave on Monday
- play on Monday
- play Monday

**Usually**, these are **action** verbs.

These uses are founds in all varieties of English.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are used.

As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=See+you+on+monday+morning%2Csee+you+monday+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CSee%20you%20on%20monday%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsee%20you%20on%20Monday%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSee%20you%20on%20Monday%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csee%20you%20monday%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsee%20you%20Monday%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSee%20you%20Monday%20morning%3B%2Cc0), example 2 is more common.

Answer (score 0):

Both adverbials are of the same leaven, they are both idiomatic. Let us look at these examples: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/adverbials-of-time

The latter, *Monday morning* is even more common, in speech and writing, as Seowjooheng Singapore has correctly stated above. The reason has been a historical easy-to-use of such adverbial phrase on practice across several centuries.
Although, the noun phrases in the function of the time adverbial, sort of *Monday morning*, *Last week* and so on are considered to be exceptions from the point of view of the English language grammarians. To see it oneself, you should have opened any grammar book on the chapter **Adverbials of time**. Many authors of such texts don't count these noun phrases as eligible adverbials of time at all also reasonably.

The reason of that is the history of the English language development from the ancient times until now. The English language in its official accepted dialect has got just three case inflections for the noun phrases: **Nominative**, **Objective for Pronouns**, **Possessive for Nouns and Pronouns**. And the meaning of a noun phrase is also determined by means of **Prepositions** and **by the position in the sentence** in relation to the **Sentence Verb Phrase** most of all.

But, once upon a time the English language had a complex inflectional system of the Noun Cases, as the German and Slavic laguages have got nowdays, which has transformed in its current analytical-prepositional syntactical and morphological forms.

Based upon such short grammatical elucidation, I should explain that the sentence *I see you* requires the *Time adverbial* in the form of the noun phrase with implied meaning of so-called theoretical Accusative Case that requires the syntax of prepositional phrase having the preposition *On* in the front position, i. e. *I see you on Monday morning*.  In the event of deviation from such syntax we may get a logical contradiction, as if with the meaning of the sentence *I see you (as) the best friend (of mine)*. It goes without saying that such syntax in the language theory of the time adverbial could go down to the main characters of the novel 'Robinson Crusoe' only, if we imagined that they would become English grammarians for a short period in the course of their adventures on an uninhabited island.

That is why, the noun phrases that are used as the Time adverbials, for example, *Monday morning* or *Last weekend* in the current English are idioms having an established meaning on practice because of the long historical usage.

Comment: I see you on Monday morning. is not grammatical in English.

Comment: *If Emilia has no success then **I see you on Monday morning** at ten o'clock at my office.*  The Italian Escape. Catherine Mangan, 2021 It is an informal meaning, to meet or accompany. The future tense in English can be in the Present Indefinite tense.

Comment: Not at all: **"If Emilia has no success then *I'll see* you on Monday morning at 10 o'clock in my office**." I'll. You should try and believe a native speaker. In that novel, the author is making a mistake on **purpose** as it is a typical mistake in English of  of Italian speakers. It sounds more "autentico".

Comment: I know that you prefer rhetorical excercises. And a bit inquisitive. What about informal usage as I stated. Did you get it? The topic here is not the First Conditionals. Time adverbials are the topic.

Comment: I only pointed it out because you pointed it out as an example of some thing. time adverbials is not the topic. The topic is the preposition **on** used with days of the week....

Comment: It seems as if you didn't read the OP question and the comments I'd offered. *On Monday morning* and *Monday morning* are both time adverbials. The former is grammatical, the latter is an idiom used as a time adverbial.

Comment: No one disputes that these are adverbs of time. Who cares? The OP wants usage. The point is about the preposition **on** versus the **null set** with **days of the week**. Your answer is overblown and not to the point at all.

Comment: Really ? I've said everything about your attitude. There is nothing new on your part.